# C function don't return list values

Tags: c, struct, return-value

Don't know why but my function don't want return values.
This is how I use this function:

```
struct element_listy *pakiet = NULL, *wsk = NULL;
pakiet = dodaj_ramke(pakiet, &frame);
```

And this is function:

```
struct element_listy* dodaj_ramke (struct element_listy *wskazanyelement, struct ramka *ramka){
    struct element_listy *wsk, *nowy;
    if (wskazanyelement == NULL) {
        wskazanyelement = (struct element_listy*)malloc(sizeof(struct element_listy)); //rezerwacja pamięci dla listy
        wskazanyelement->ramka=(struct ramka*)malloc(sizeof(struct ramka)); //zalookowanie pamieci dla elementu listy
        wskazanyelement->first = wskazanyelement; //Pierwszy element to lista obecna
        wskazanyelement->next = NULL; // Drugi element nie istnieje
        wskazanyelement->previous = wskazanyelement; //wskazanyelement->first->ramka; // poprzedni element to wskazanie na liste obecną
        memcpy(wskazanyelement->first->ramka, ramka, sizeof(struct ramka)); //skopiowanie pod pierwszy element listy
        return wskazanyelement; //zwróć liste
    } else {
        wsk = wskazanyelement; //pomocnicza lista dla listy
        while (wsk->next != NULL) { //przechodzimy na koniec listy
            wsk = wsk->next;
        }
        nowy = (struct element_listy*)malloc(sizeof(struct element_listy)); //lookowanie pamieci dla listy
        nowy->ramka=(struct ramka*)malloc(sizeof(struct ramka)); //zalookowanie wskazanie na elementy listy
        memcpy(nowy->ramka, ramka, sizeof(struct ramka)); //kopiowanie pod element listy
        nowy->first = wskazanyelement; //pierwszy element pomocniczej to pobrana ramka
        wsk->next = nowy; //następny element
        wsk->previous = wsk;
        return wskazanyelement;
    }
}
```

In debuger I see that returned *wskazanyelement* have values copied from *ramka*. But when function end and I go to next step the *pakiet* is empty. Why? I return copied data on the end of function.

Comment: You should send the wskazanyelement by pointer or by reference. In your could you send a copy of it. function should be `struct element_listy* dodaj_ramke (struct element_listy *&wskazanyelement, struct ramka *&ramka)`

Comment: And please to make it more easy, try to submit your code in English comments and names, so we can follow up

Comment: What? I see something like that frist time. And compiler return error that "expect ; or , or ) befor &".  
I thinking that must be something else because on virtual machine the same code works with out problems.

Comment: Sorry send a pointer to the pointer  you want to change `struct element_listy* dodaj_ramke (struct element_listy **wskazanyelement, struct ramka **ramka)`

Comment: It is clear that you are sending a copy of your pointer which points to `NULL`, so that the local pointer in your function when is allocated it will not reflect back on your original pointer.

Comment: But this are a input data and this is fine, because mcpy works fine and I see copied data to wskazanyelement

Comment: Now I have error that: wskazanyelement is a pointer. I don't think this is it. On all examples what I saw is like me. And why it works on older eclipse and ubuntu?

Comment: Now i saw that i have warring 
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’ listy.c
Maybe in newest gcc version somthing change?

Comment: The warning means you maybe not including string.h for memcpy

Comment: Yes it should be a pointer!!

Comment: See this similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/12308813/5504460

Comment: Hi,
Unfortunatly but you haven't right, because I copy project to virtual machine with ubuntu14.04/eclipse_neon/gcc4.9 and it's works. On this computer i have gcc6.2.0-10 and I see problem when i try remove it because I get error that: it don't have libgcc1. Reinstallation don't fix issue.

Comment: I am just wondering if you have tried using double pointers before saying it isn't

Comment: I try as like in your example. Firstly i have errors like: "wskazanyelement is a pointer", but when i fix it, program result is the same.

Comment: How did you fix it

Comment: Lol now i try to bac to that, but i get error. Yesterday it was build 
`struct element_listy* dodaj_ramke (struct element_listy **head, struct ramka **ramka){
 struct element_listy *wsk, *nowy;
 if (head == NULL) {
  head = (struct element_listy*)malloc(sizeof(struct element_listy));
  head.ramka=(struct ramka*)malloc(sizeof(struct ramka));
  head.first = head;
  head.next = NULL;
  head.previous = head;
  memcpy(head.first.ramka, ramka, sizeof(struct ramka));
  return head;`

Comment: Sure it must give errors! Also the GCC thing, it may work by chance its undefined behaviour not the real cause of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this issue. This isn't problem with pointer. Like I say this i problem with gcc. I must downgrade this because upgrade start issue.
I was a gcc6. I was remove it:

```
aptitude remove gcc-6
```

But this remove main gcc also, so I was must redefinie it

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
```

After clean project and rebuild it, my function start work currectly.